# Failing to link to SFML libraries using Makefile even though it works as a one liner

Tags: makefile, compilation, linker, g++, sfml

Here is my directory structure :

```
.
├── a.out
├── assets
│   └── ...
├── build
│   ├── apps
│   └── objects
├── include
│   └── engine
│       └── Class.h
├── Makefile
└── src
    ├── engine
    │   └── Class.cpp
    └── program.cpp
```

I can compile `program.cpp` into `a.out` using the following command :

```
g++ src/engine/*.cpp src/program.cpp -Iinclude/ -L/usr/lib -lstdc++ -lm -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system -Wall
```

While this works, this project is likely to grow and obviously making a serious Makefile would be preferable to direct compiling with a one liner. So I've used a Makefile format that I've used many times before, and that works perfectly fine but I've never linked it to outside libraries in the past. Here is the Makefile I'm using :

```
CXX      := -g++
CXXFLAGS := -std=gnu++0x -g -Wall
LDFLAGS  := -L/usr/lib -lstdc++ -lm -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system
BUILD    := ./build
OBJ_DIR  := $(BUILD)/objects
APP_DIR  := $(BUILD)/apps
TARGET   := program
INCLUDE  := -Iinclude/
SRC      := $(wildcard src/engine/*.cpp) $(wildcard src/*.cpp)
OBJECTS  := $(SRC:%.cpp=$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o)

all: build $(APP_DIR)/$(TARGET)

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: %.cpp
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) -o $@ -c $<

$(APP_DIR)/$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) $(LDFLAGS) -o $(APP_DIR)/$(TARGET) $(OBJECTS)

.PHONY: all build clean debug release

build:
    @mkdir -p $(APP_DIR)
    @mkdir -p $(OBJ_DIR)

debug: CXXFLAGS += -DDEBUG -g
debug: all

release: CXXFLAGS += -O2
release: all

clean:
    -@rm -rvf $(OBJ_DIR)/*
    -@rm -rvf $(APP_DIR)/*
```

However, this leads to compilation errors, in the form of undefined references to SFML methods :

```
./build/objects/src/engine/Class.o: In function `Class::draw()':
/dir/Class.cpp:60: undefined reference to `sf::RenderTarget::getView() const'
```

I'm confused as to why this happens given that the one liner above compiles fine. The Makefile also works just fine if I remove all references to SFML from my code. Were the added `LDFLAGS` not enough even though they're all that's needed to make my one liner link to SFML ? If so, what else is needed ?

Comment: Wow... that actually did it. I didn't even realize changing the order of something like that could matter. I think this would be worthwhile to point out in an answer. Would you mind writing that and perhaps adding a line or 2 as to what's going on here ? I'm genuinely curious as to how you figured that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [gcc link options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html)

**`-llibrary`**

> It makes a difference where in the command you write this option; the linker searches and processes libraries and object files in the order they are specified. Thus, `foo.o -lz bar.o` searches library `z` after file `foo.o` but before `bar.o`. If `bar.o` refers to functions in `z`, those functions may not be loaded.

So put the libraries (`-l<lib_1> ... -l<lib_x>`) last on the line, after your object files.

Comment: I am extra grateful that you did not add "RTFM" to your comment, as I would have very much deserved it XD In my defense, I've somehow miraculously never encountered this before. In all my years of C++ I must have always been linking in the right order out of sheer happenstance.

Comment: @ticster I actually replicated your project structure and made a small program in it myself before I noticed :-)

Comment: This is the exact reason there are two different "standard" make variables for linking libraries: `LDFLAGS` which are supposed to contain the flags (like `-Ldir/to/foo`) and `LDLIBS` which are supposed to contain the libraries (like `-lfoo`).  Then the default linker recipe is (the equivalent of) `$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@`

Comment: @MadScientist thanks for the tip. I'll change my flags accordingly.

Comment: @TedLyngmo wait... By that logic shouldn't the LDFLAGS go first rather than last ? Since my own code depends on it ?

Comment: @ticster The name of the variable doesn't matter other than it may confuse other readers of your makefile. Personally, I have a great number of packages that I link with when playing around (and I'm to lazy to modify the makefile so I just link with everything). I have one variable for each package: `PACKAGE_n = -L path/to/libs -llib1 -llib2 -llib3` and then I have `LIBS = $(PACKAGE_1) ... $(PACKAGE_X)`. I put that `$(LIBS)` last, with all the `-L`'s in it.

Comment: @TedLyngmo sure but I meant w.r.t. the order of the flags, not their names. Since my objects depend on the external libs, how come it works when LDFLAGS comes after OBJECTS ? Shouldn't it be the other way around ?

Comment: @ticster No, it's the other way around. If `file.o` uses `func()` and `func()` is in the library `funcs` then: `file.o -lfuncs` resolves it. Think of it as the linker creates a list of unresolved functions. Whenever it sees a function being used that's not been used before, it will be put in that list. If that function was present in a library already scanned, it'll be missed, but when it scans the later libraries, it'll check for that function too.